# Jenkins Pipeline - Groovy Extended Choice parameter is not working. Error : Invalid parameter type "extendedChoice"

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am getting an error Invalid parameter type "extendedChoice" when running my groovy pipeline with extended choice parameter. We have two jenkins running in our environment. One jenkins server is well and good with extended choice parameter whereas other was troubling with this error Invalid parameter type "extendedChoice". There are few differences between two jenkins i.e., versions of jenkins and extended choice parameter plugin. **Working** Jenkins version is `2.204.1` and extended choices parameter plugin verion is `0.78`. **Not working** jenkins version is `2.194` and extended choices parameter plugin verion `0.76`. And there are differences in pipeline and groovy plugin as well between these two jenkins. I don't think this error is due to the versions of plugin in the not working jenkins. Please refer the below piece of code I used

```
extendedChoice(name: 'PIPELINE_MODE', defaultValue: 'Build & Deploy', multiSelectDelimiter: ',', quoteValue: false, saveJSONParameterToFile: false, type: 'PT_RADIO',
                value:'Rollback, Build & Deploy',
                visibleItemCount: 3,
                description: 'This is to describe the nature of the pipeline'
        )
```

I can't get the root cause for this issue. Can anyone please advise what I've missed or what is wrong.

Comment: Is this part of the `parameters` class or a stand-alone method invocation?

Comment: did you figure this out? getting the same error

Comment: This issue was due to the version of extended choice plugin. I have updated from 0.76 to 0.78 and so it works well now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This issue was due to the version of extended choice plugin. I have upgraded the version from 0.76 to 0.78. it works well now. Thanks